# JBOSS 5.1 does not work in CentOS 4.8

Tags: centos, jboss5.x

For some reason I need to use CentOS 4.8.

I installed Java 1.6.26 and JBOSS 5.1 on CentOS 4.8. However, When I use `./run.sh` to run JBOSS I get the following message:

```
/bin/run.jaring required file: /opt/java/jboss
```

where `/opt/java/jboss` is the link to the JBOSS installation directory. Nothing else happens and there is no log.

I tried the search the error message, but got no hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

The problem was because I copied a '.sh' file from another linux host via a windows machine. During the copy (or transfer), a '\r' character is inserted at the end of each line of the .sh file. And this .sh file set the path variable in linux. Because of the '\r', the path is not set correctly.

After I remove the '\r' from the end of the lines in .sh file, everything works.